# How to validate incoming files in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, validation, azure-data-factory

is there a way to create a template to validate incoming files including such checks as empty file checks, format, data types, record counts along, and will stop the workflow if any of the checks fail. The solution for this requirement should consider multiple file-formats and reduce the burden on ETL processing and checks to enable scale.

File transfer to occur either by trigger or data currency rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Factory more focus on data transfer, not the file filter.

We could using the [get metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity) and  [if-condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) to achieve some of the these feature, such as validate the file format, size, file name. You can use Get Metadata to get the file properties and If-condition can help you filter the file.

But that's too complexed for Data Factory to help you achieve all the features you want.

**Update:**

For example, we can parameter a file in source, :

Create dataset parameter `filename` and pipeline parameter `name`:
[image]

Using `Get metadata` to get its properties: `Item type`, `Exists`, `Size`, `Item name`. 
[image]

Output:
[image]

For example, We can build [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) in `if-condition` to judge  if it's empyt(size=0):

```
@equals(activity('Get Metadata1').output.size,0)
```

If Ture means it's empty, False no empty. Then we can build the workflow in True or False active.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, @Leon Yue. I looked at the document you provided. However, I do not seem to understand how to go about this. Could you please explain further. A sample script will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Caleb, you're welcome. I updated my answer, hope it's helpfull.

Comment: Thank you @Leon Yue. I was thinking this can be achieved with a PowerShell script.

Comment: @Caleb You're welcome, I'm glad if I could help you. PowerShell script may be another way, really hope you could achieve that! In the end, can you think about mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much, have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrate similar techniques to validate source files and take appropriate downstream actions in your pipeline based on those values [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWSkJdtiJNM).